# T SQL how to add extra elements in xml

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Hi im trying to generate xml from my t sql query. But im having problems with adding extra elements in my xml. Or is it even possible to do that. my sql query is like this.

```
    SELECT 
        m.DeviceId as IndividualItemNo,
        Name = 'B',
        w.BTime as Value,
        CAST(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8), w.EndTS, 112) AS INT) AS [Date], 
        CONVERT(VARCHAR(5), w.EndTS,108) + '+0000' AS [Time],
        g.GroupName
    FROM Machine m
        INNER JOIN [Group] g ON m.GroupId = g.GroupId
        INNER JOIN [EDWCompany] e ON g.CompanyKey = e.CompanyKey
        LEFT JOIN WorkingPass w ON m.MachineId = w.MachineId and w.WorkingPassId = (SELECT MAX(w.WorkingPassId) FROM WorkingPass w WHERE MachineId = m.MachineId )
    WHERE g.CompanyKey = 105
    GROUP BY  m.DeviceId, w.EndTS , w.BTime , g.GroupName, e.CompanyNo, m.MachineId
    ORDER BY m.DeviceId 
    FOR XML PATH ('IndividualItem'), ROOT ('IndividualItem_Report'), ELEMENTS
```

My XML result:

```
<IndividualItem_Report>
  <IndividualItem>
    <IndividualItemNo>027FDF3014953</IndividualItemNo>
    <Name>B</Name>
    <Value>3535</Value>
    <Date>20130221</Date>
    <Time>10:32+0000</Time>
    <GroupName>TARKETT AB</GroupName>
  </IndividualItem>
</IndividualItem_Report>
```

But i want to add extra elements. So this is what i want.

```
<IndividualItem_Report>
    <IndividualItem>
        <IndividualItemNo>027FDF3014953</IndividualItemNo>
        <HourMeterList>
            <HourMeter>
                <Name>B</Name>
                <Value>3535</Value>
                <Date>20130221</Date>
                <Time>10:32+0000</Time>
                <GroupName>TARKETT AB</GroupName>
            </HourMeter>
        </HourMeterList>
    </IndividualItem>
</IndividualItem_Report>
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume HourMeterList is a multi value

From working code
This is just part of the select list

```
,(select top 1 'MV' 
  from docMVenum1 with (nolock) 
    where docMVenum1.sID = docSVsys.sID and docMVenum1.enumID = '179') 
  as 'RFPResponse/@SVMV'
,(select top 1 'RFP Response#' 
  from docMVenum1 with (nolock) 
    where docMVenum1.sID = docSVsys.sID and docMVenum1.enumID = '179') 
  as 'RFPResponse/@displayName'
 , (select docEnum1.value 
      from docMVenum1 with (nolock) 
      join docEnum1 with (nolock) 
      on docEnum1.enumID = docMVenum1.enumID and docEnum1.valueID = docMVenum1.valueID
      where docMVenum1.sID = docSVsys.sID and docMVenum1.enumID = '179' 
      order by docEnum1.value 
      FOR XML PATH (''), type 
   ) as [RFPResponse]
```

Sample output

```
<RFPResponse SVMV="MV" displayName="RFP Response#">
  <value>RFPa</value>
  <value>RFPb</value>
</RFPResponse>
```

Comment: Hi! Yes it can be a multi value but in this case isn´t. In this case i just need to add it too my xml result. Is tehre a way to do this ?

Comment: I really dont get it, So the only thing i need to add is select more columns then us as after it ?

Comment: I really don't get your question "only thing i need to add is select more columns then us as after it ?"  That from working code.   What have you tried?

Comment: I have tried to add as "HourList" after the inner joint but then i got wrong elements not in the order i want it. Is it possible to wrap . <Name>B</Name> <Value>3535</Value> <Date>20130221</Date> <Time>10:32+0000</Time> <GroupName>TARKETT AB</GroupName> into 2 others elemetns ?

Comment: in your example i got extra attributs only.